# When using first_or_create, in the after_create callback, the Model queries get extra conditions added automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For explanation purposes, I'm going to create a brand new Rails (3.2.13) project using SQLite.

```
rails new TestApp
cd TestApp/
rake db:create
rails g model Blog name:string description:string
rake db:migrate
```

This is the content of the `Blog` model.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  after_create :print_other_name


  private

  def print_other_name
    # Just for example, running a query here.
    blog = Blog.first
  end
end
```

Then open a `rails console`.

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > blog = Blog.where( name: 'First Blog' ).first_or_create!( description: 'This is the first blog' )

  Blog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."name" = 'First Blog' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (63.9ms)  INSERT INTO "blogs" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 09 May 2013 11:30:31 UTC +00:00], ["description", "This is the first blog"], ["name", "First Blog"], ["updated_at", Thu, 09 May 2013 11:30:31 UTC +00:00]]
  ======>>>>>>> Blog Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."name" = 'First Blog' LIMIT 1
   (1.5ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Blog id: 1, name: "First Blog", description: "This is the first blog", created_at: "2013-05-09 11:30:31", updated_at: "2013-05-09 11:30:31">
```

In the above code block, please look at the query that has been run after the `INSERT` query:

```
Blog Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."name" = 'First Blog' LIMIT 1
```

This is the query that has been generated by the `Blog.first` line in the model's `after_create`.

What should have been a simple `LIMIT 1` query without any conditions, now has a `name` condition added on to the query. And after a lot of testing, I realised that the condition being added on is the condition that is mentioned in the `Blog.where( name: 'First Blog' ).first_or_create!....` line.

In other words, **whatever conditions I use in the `where` before the `first_or_create` seems to get added automatically to all the queries run in the `after_create` callback.**

I can't imagine why this would be expected behaviour, but if it is, I can't find it documented anywhere.

Does anybody have any insight into this behaviour? This is breaking all my queries in the `after_create` callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `first_or_create` wraps your whole query in a scope defined by the where clause. You can solve this in two ways:

1. Instead of using `first_or_create` use `find_or_create_by` like

   ```
   Blog.find_or_create_by( name: 'First Blog' )
   ```
2. Use `unscoped` in all your callbacks that includes a query like:

   ```
   def print_other_name
     # Just for example, running a query here.
     blog = Blog.unscoped.first
   end
   ```